# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'c:\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-strip''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer (*original post)

[Build Error: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952796/build-error-execution-failed-for-task-apptransformnativelibswithstripdebugsy)

you have to uninstall install NDK
[image]